# Google OAuth userinfo method doesn't return email address

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

I'm using Google APIs with Postman and I'm using to retrieve my token and it works.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code={my_code}
```

[image]

Now, with **access_token** I would like to have the user data
so I'm calling this method:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={my_access_token}
```

But my response is

[image]

I already tryied with userinfo.email but resonse is not found
[image]

Is there any way to get the user email?
Thanks

---

update: tryied also setting scope to auth call
[image]

and userinfo call
[image]

But no email returned.

Comment: you have a return between your scopes it just needs to be a space.

Comment: it's a space. It seems a return because it's too long but I swear it's a space.

Comment: First image your see the authorization tab you have no auth selected.

Comment: what I have to set?

Comment: Try oauth2 then you should be able to add the client id and everything there.   The user info endpoint wont return all the claims all the time if you have added the email scope then you really should be going though the people api.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo):

> **email**  is provided only if your scope included the email scope value.

To do that, set an additional scope to your application:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

You can go to Developer's Console then add the scope by [customizing](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#consentpageexperience) your user consent screen. The goal here is you need to see the `userinfo.email` along with `userinfo.profile` scope whenever you
retrieve your access token using Postman.

Another way is you have to generate another [authorization code](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow#example-authorization-url) again. When authorizing, you will be asked to include a scope on your request and there you include the two scopes that you need.

Comment: I tried running this command:

`curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={my_access_token}`

And got my access token from this [website](https://any-api.com/googleapis_com/oauth2/console/userinfo/oauth2_userinfo_get) and it works, so it's very likely that you're missing the email scope.

Comment: I can't understand. Do I have to change the First call?

Comment: As you can see on your latest image, there's still only one scope from the response which is `userinfo.profile`. You don't apply the scope when you exchange the auth code for the access token. You apply the scope when you're getting the authorization code. You can try here on [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to see how it works. You should be able to see the scopes on People API v1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222722/discussion-between-donnald-c-and-martina).

Comment: You cant just add a new scope you need to reauthencate your user, you need to see the consent screen pop up again.

Comment: @DaImTo can you help me continuing this discussion in chat?

Answer (score 0):

The userinfo.endpoint is not designed or guaranteed to return the claimed every time.   If you want to get the users email address every time and have included the email scope you should be going though the People api.

[People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

## response

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/117200475532672775346",
  "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoEAQIFByIMR3BzQkR2cnI1ZGc9",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "verified": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "117200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "verified": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "117200475532672775346"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@gmail.com",
      "type": "home",
      "formattedType": "Home"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@gmail.com",
      "type": "home",
      "formattedType": "Home"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@hotmail.com",
      "type": "other",
      "formattedType": "Other"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@daimto.com",
      "type": "other",
      "formattedType": "Other"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxx@eg.dk",
      "type": "work",
      "formattedType": "Work"
    }
  ]
}
```

beyond that i think you should consider using the auth tab in postman and selecting, oauth2 then you should be able to add the client id and everything there. Which is much easier then swapping out all the codes yourself.

Comment: ok, I will try this method but I can't see the param with access token.
If I use this method https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses
Wich other params I have to set (Client id, client secret,access token?)

Comment: Send the bearer access token as an authorization header as shown in my answer

Comment: I can't understand your curl command because I'm using C# WebRequests and now Postman.The url is https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresse. The header parameters are Authorization and Accept?

Comment: Why arent you just using the Google .net client library? ASP .net or Asp .net core?  Why are you even doing this with postman?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this endpoint:

```
https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
```

You can check all OAuth endpoints by going to this url: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration